# File upload time limitation

Tags: php, time, upload

i am working on project where user can upload the files. I am confused now ! 
I want suggestion and idea to develop this system.

When user reach the 5 file uploads after that for each upload there will be 2 min delay for each file upload.

example rapidshare

if any one have idea then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just maintain a field in `database` which saves the `last file upload date and time` and if the uploads reach to the limit of 5 then before uploading file check that last file upload time. If the `difference` between `last file upload time` and `current time` is greater than `2 minutes` then allow the file to be uploaded otherwise give `message` to the user to wait before he can upload next file.